# hibernate.properties not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

```
  <form action="register.jsp" method="post">
id:<input type="text" name="id"/><br><br/>
Name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br><br/>
Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br><br/>
Email ID:<input type="text" name="email"/><br><br/>
<input type="submit" value="register"/>

</form>
```

the above file is index.jsp

```
<%@page import="com.javatpoint.mypack.UserDao"%>
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.javatpoint.mypack.User"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>
<%
obj.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
obj.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
obj.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
try
{
System.out.println("--------->"+obj.getName());

int i=UserDao.register(obj);
if(i>0)
{
out.print("You are successfully registered");
}
else
{
    out.print("registration failed");
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{

    out.print("You are not registered");
}
%>
```

the above file is register.jsp

```
package com.javatpoint.mypack;

public class User {
public int id;
public String name,password,email;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


}
```

the above file is user.java

```
package com.javatpoint.mypack;


import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

public class UserDao {

    public static int register(User u){
        int i=0;
        try{

        Session session=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();

        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
        t.begin();

        i=(Integer)session.save(u);

        t.commit();
        session.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return i;
    }

}
```

the above program is UserDao.java
while executing the application it is hibernate.properties not found error 
please reply me why it is occuring

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate by default at startup looks for hibernate.properties and hibernate.cfg.xml and logs a debug message if those aren't found. So disable debug/info for hibernate and you will not see the message.see http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?127317-hibernate-properties-with-JavaConfig

also see [hibernate properties not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495088/hibernate-properties-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure .properties file in the root of class path, Which means if you have something like

```
--src //source folder which all files in it will be compiled/copied to deployment
   --user   //those are folders which has classes in it
   --dao    //those are folders which has classes in it
  hibernate.properties //should be here
```

if it is above structure then `new Configuration().configure()` should find it automatically, or if you do not want to put it there then you can do something like:
`new Configuration().configure(path)`
Or see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677783/where-to-place-hibernate-cfg-xml/12677979#12677979)

Comment: i execute the above program as u said but even it showing the same error.if had any example program on jsp as front end and hibernate as backend plz post the link